# What Does Being Spiritual Mean?

Tags: materialism

When people say they are spiritual, although atheist, what do they mean, if they mean something at all? Can you claim being spiritual if you don't believe in gods, ghosts and the like?

Is there a spirit, from a non-religious point of view, as a separate thing from the mind?

Comment: It would be helpful if you pointed out a particular example.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: @iphigenie: try to interpret the question as "what is the spirit?" Do you have to believe in something like ghosts to believe there is a 'spirit', separated from the mind? The question can have a philosophical interpretation.

Comment: Good edit, I retract the close vote (:

Answer (score 1):

When an atheist says she's spiritual, she means that she finds beauty and balance in the world around her and in her very own self. There are lots of activities other than the ones that have to do with religion that you can participate in that will get you that outlook on life: art, science, philosophy, etc.

Comment: The term has some geographic variation, this is probably more true in the US than in England where it has a strong New Age connotation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Age

Comment: @Lucas you Brits are crazy :)

Answer (score 1):

Atheist Sam Harris wrote a [blog post](http://www.samharris.org/blog/item/a-plea-for-spirituality) on this:

> Of course, “spiritual” and its cognates have some unfortunate associations unrelated to their etymology—and I will do my best to cut those ties as well. But there seems to be no other term (apart from the even more problematic “mystical” or the more restrictive “contemplative”) with which to discuss the deliberate efforts some people make to overcome their feeling of separateness—through meditation, psychedelics, or other means of inducing non-ordinary states of consciousness.

He also summarizes Christopher Hitchens (Britisch American) take on spirituality:

> He [Hitchens] spoke instead of the spiritual pleasures afforded by certain works of poetry, music, and art

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably better suited for English.se than philosophy.se, but the basic answer is that spiritual has to do with spirit. But what is spirit?

One answer could be the Holy Spirit for Christians. I think there's a similar concept available to Jews and Muslims but I don't know as much about that. By extension, there's a meaning of Spirit which refers to our consciousness as a group in Hegel. Apart from the Hegelian version, this is an odd one for an atheist.

But Spirit does not always mean obtaining from a religious or heavenly realm. Instead, spiritual can be a synonym for mental. Thus, Hegel's *Phenomenology of Spirit* is translated in one contemporary translation as *Phenomenology of Mind*. Thus, "spirit" in English sometimes translates *Geist* in German. In the same way, it can mean experiencing psychological enjoyment at something or merely enjoying it for non-material reasons. Or to give a different language's take 精神的 means "spiritual" but also could be translated as "psychological."

(For Hegel, the two turn out to be synonymous since self-consciousness is the ultimate property of the divine for us... but I digress)

A further possibility and one that should raise eyebrows coming from an atheist is a panentheist sense of meaning in nature. On such a reading, the spirit is in us and things, and our connection with those things is "spiritual" as this is the unifying element of our diverse matter.

Answer (score 0):

Re: *"Is there a spirit, from a non-religious point of view, as a separate thing from the mind?"*

I would say yes, inasmuch as an emotional state, such as shock, is not the same as mind itself.  But spirit is more that just a state.  As the notes below show, it is also like a flame, and other things besides.  It has a complex and intriguing origin.

The notes begin with two quotes from Jacques Derrida's essay, 'Of Spirit' (1987).  As you will see, the meanings are generally quite down-to-earth, although they express the extraordinariness of emotional states -- spirited states, if you like.

The other angle, the burning flame analogy is interesting.  You may have seen pictures of disciples with [burning flames](http://communio.stblogs.org/index.php/category/easter-ascension-pentecost/page/9/) on their heads, or shining halos at least.

*Image from*  [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentecost)

[image]

Jacques Derrida:

> What is spirit?
>
> The reply is inscribed in maxims which translate  certain poetic statements by Trakl, in a form which  one would call ontological if
>   ontology were still the  dominant regime of these texts.
>
> "*Doch was ist der Geist?*" Heidegger indeed  asks.  What is spirit?  Reply: "*Der Geist ist das  Flammende*."  Further on, "*Der Geist ist
>   Flamme*."
>
> How to translate?  Spirit is what inflames? Rather, what inflames *itself*, setting *itself* on fire,  setting fire to *itself*? 
>   Spirit is flame.  A flame  which inflames, or which inflames *itself*:
>   both at  once, the one and the other, the one the other. *Con*-flagration of the two in the very  con-*flagration*.
>
> (Of Spirit, page 84)

Martin Heidegger (translated by J. Derrida):

> The burning up is the radiance of a reddening  glare.  What burns
>   itself up is Being-outside-itself  (*das Ausser-sich*) which illuminates
>   and makes  shine, which also, however (*indessen auch*), can  devour
>   tirelessly and consume everything up to  and including the white of
>   the ash (*in das Weisse  der Asche verzehren kann*).
>
> "The flame is the brother of the palest" is what  we read in the poem *Verwandlung des Bösen*  (*Transmutation of the Evil One*).  Trakl
>   envisages  "spirit" on the basis of this essence which is named  in
>   the originary meaning (*in der ursprünglichen  Bedeutung*) of the word
>   "*Geist*," for *gheis* means:  to be thrown (*aufgebracht*), transported [or
>   transposed, deported: *entsetzt*, again -- and I  believe this is the
>   most determining predicate],  outside itself (*ausser sich*).
>
> (Of Spirit, page 98)

---------<<<{{O}}>>>---------

> ... *spirit* was initially used  to translate Greek *pneuma* and
>   Hebrew *ruah*,  starting in about 1250, and all versions of the  Bible
>   from Wyclif onward use *spirit* in translation  of the Greek and
>   Hebrew.  Prior to the Middle  Ages, however, *ghost* was used.  It
>   comes from the  Indo-European root *gheis*- "fear or amazement",  and
>   there are descendants of that root in most of  the Germanic languages,
>   all of them possessing  similar meanings.  Some etymologists believe
>   that  Sanskrit *he'das* "anger" is related, and the general  meaning
>   of related words outside of the Germanic  language family appears to
>   have been "fury,  anger".

http://www.takeourword.com/Issue082.html

> **Geist**. m. Old and Middle High German *geist*, Old  Saxon *gêst* from West
>   Germanic **gaista-* m.:  "supernatural character or being, emotional
>   state;"  also in Old English *gâst*, Old Frisian *jêst*. From the 
>   Indo-European root **gheis-d-* : "to be out of one's  mind" [*au er sich
>   sein*], also in Sanskrit *hîd*-: "to be  angry" [*zürnen*]; unexpanded in
>   Avestan *zaêsa*-:  "terrible, dreadful" [*schauderhaft*], Gothic 
>   *usgeinan*: "to be frightened" and *usgaisjan*: "to  frighten"
>   [*erschrecken*], Old Norse *geiskafullr*:  "completely frightened." To the
>   extensive family of 
>   **ghe/ghei-* : "yawn" [*gähnen*], belongs also the  sense "to open wide one's mouth", hence probably  a derived root **gheies-*: "Wide opening
>   of the  mouth"; the -*d*- is probably a short grade of **dô-*:  "to give."
>   Therefore **gheis-d-* would mean: "to  bring about a wide opening of the
>   mouth"  [*Mundaufsperrung herbeiführen*]; "to make  someone open his
>   mouth wide."

http://www.albany.edu/offcourse/july99/hache.html

In regard to Beowulf:

> *Gæst* occurs 8 times apparently meaning "ghost,"  or "demon" only, as a
>   masculine noun, with  variations of 4 compound nouns (*'ellen-*, *ellor-*,
>   *geoscaft-*, and *wæl-*'). At least two instances are  uncertain.  *Gæst*
>   (also spelled *gist*,) occurs 9 times,  with the apparent primary
>   meaning of "guest."  Lexicographers from Bosworth and Toller  onwards
>   have differentiated in their editing of  instances of this word or
>   words, according to  whether they see Grendel and his Mother as 
>   demonic. ... A more recent editor suggests that  only context can
>   decide. The difference is  important because the words seem to
>   distinguish  between the natural and the demonic, accentuating 
>   Grendel's and his Mother's monstrous natures. *The American Heritage
>   Dictionary of Indo-European Roots* notes that *gæst* meaning "guest"
>   derives  from **ghos-ti*, meaning "stranger, guest, host," and  "someone
>   with whom one has reciprocal duties of  hospitality." Reflexes of the
>   word include  Germanic **gastiz*, Latin *hostis* "enemy" and Greek  *xenos*,
>   "stranger." Lewis and Short note that Latin  word *hostis*, derives from
>   the Sanskrit root **ghas-*  to eat, consume, or destroy" and that the
>   Germanic  *gast* is derived from the same word. The  compound of this
>   word in Latin, *hospes*, adds the  suffix "pa" "to feed," thus combining
>   the idea of  feeding with the word for stranger, and then  contracting
>   to "hospites" or "he who entertains a  stranger." *The American
>   Heritage Dictionary of  Indo-European Roots* gives *gist* as deriving
>   from 
>   **gheis* in an unclear original meaning, having to do  with "fear or amazement," with the "suffixed o-  grade form **ghois-do* in Germanic
>   **gaistaz*, a  ghost." The *Oxford English Dictionary* notes that  word's etymological relations are "fury, anger....  the root "**gheis-*,
>   **ghois-* appears with cognate  sense in ON *geisa* to rage, Gothic *usgaisjan* to  terrify; outside Teutonic the derivatives seem to  point
>   to a primary sense "to wound, tear, pull to  pieces." This last may
>   suggest a link between the  two original words, since both roots have
>   to do  with consumption, with a possible development  from the
>   relatively neutral **ghas-* , "to consume",  to the more negative
>   **gheis-*, "fear." The first  would note what is expected from a social  relationship, the offering and consumption of food,  while the second
>   would encompass the possible  excesses of a guest who destroys.
>   Simple,  ritualized consumption gives way to destruction  and
>   fragmentation.  The negative association of the  supernatural world
>   with cases of excess would also  make sense, in that enforcement and
>   punishment of  those who break the treaties is projected into the 
>   realm of the gods, as numerous examples in Greek  demonstrate. The
>   case for reading the disputed  words in *Beowulf* as either "guest" or
>   as "ghost,"  or as reflexes of the same idea, cannot be solved  here,
>   since there is no syntactical or prosodic  reason to prefer one to the
>   other.

http://www.mun.ca/mst/heroicage/issues/5/Anderson1.html

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers, just one thing to add. I have seen different uses of the term "spiritual" used by atheists:

1) In the first sense, it is metaphorical. This is the point of the Hitchens quote from jeroenk. Quotes by Einstein, Sagan, and other similar types likely fit into this category.

2) The second sense is "spiritual" in the New Age, mysticism sense of trying to connect to something that transcends matter. For an actual atheist, I can't imagine this point of view is internally consistent. If you deny that there is anything divine and that the universe consists only of the matter, trying to connect to something that transcends matter doesn't make sense.

3) Adoption of religious practices for non-religious purposes, with the primary example being meditation, are sometimes called "spiritual," even though there is no claim to a "spirit" being involved.

Comment: Regarding point 2, living beings are already in a form of existence that transcends matter.  In an ordinary sense it is full of spirit.  Perhaps it is when people focus on it they become 'spiritual', but that doesn't seem very zen.  In fact your internally consistent atheist sounds more zen, and more spiritual in a different way.